# How to troubleshoot s3 key not found error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have read the docs and the questions and answers here. I am hosting a website on s3. It loads the landing page just fine and also navigates to the next page. But on page refresh, it throws the key not found error for the key `about`, I'm not really sure what the key is supposed to be.  For reference, it hits `'/'` fine, and also `'/about'`. But on page refresh, it throws the error and I have to reenter the URL again for it to register. This is my first deployment to s3. Also, a bit of extra information, the about page, hits an API on component load. Here is my bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy-ID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hosting a single page app (SPA) in an S3 bucket. You're using react and probably using react-router. Your friendly URLs like `/about` aren't immediately compatible with S3 because if your app GETs `/about` then it will fail because you do not have an object in your S3 bucket called `about`.

You have a couple of options:

1. configure S3 static website hosting so that the error document is `index.html`
2. rewrite the url with a #!/ prefix (see [here](https://viastudio.com/hosting-a-reactjs-app-with-routing-on-aws-s3/))

Comment: Awesome thank you!. I used the first option for now. I'm not sure what the hostname will eventually be yet, so I might revisit the 2nd option you provided. My only question is, will this cause any errors if there are actual errors and there is not error.html?

Comment: Cool, This is my first real react app. I will start researching that. Thanks again so much!